# How to remove the Mobile Twitter Splash Screen?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, url, twitter

I have an iPhone app that has a Twitter page tab... however, every time someone goes to it... it loads the following splash page, I can't figure out how to remove this splash screen when loading a twitter page?

My current code is

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/TwitterNAME"]]];
```

I would prefer not to use a table view to show tweets...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append this string to the URL: `?skip_interstitial=true`, so it results as:

```
http://twitter.com/TwitterNAME?skip_interstitial=true
```

Probably you wanna format a string with the whole URL structure:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/%s?skip_interstitial=true",TwitterNameVar]
```

Resulting something like:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/%s?skip_interstitial=true",TwitterNameVar]]]];
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how the hell did you find out about the parameter `skip_interstitial`?!?

Comment: I opened it on Safari browser and changed the user agent to Safari iOS iPhone; then I searched in the code and just noticed it.